# Multi module maven Vs Micro-service architecture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, microservices

Have to create a project template for my project so i am confusing what to use in between multimodule maven or microservices(eureka).

Couples of doubt/questions i have, if anybody please help me out that will be great.

1. When to use Multimodule maven and when to use microservice ?
2. Let's suppose we have utility files which can be used by any service, so it will be a different spring boot application for utlity or in each spring project we have to keep the utility file.
3. If we have 3 microservices, i don't want to give access to one of services , how we can achieve that like for multimodule maven we can just comment it out the project from the parent pom.xml but how we can do that in microservice.
4. How we can communicate between 2 services except restTemplate.

Comment: `LDD` -> multimodule , `DDD` -> Microservices

Comment: @emotionlessbananas : can you provide any reference ?

Comment: I think you have some further reading to do, you are opposing maven (which is a way of organising source code / compiling it / assembling it) and microservices which is a way of architecting functionnality in different applications. Maven in and of itself, with or without multimodule, can build monolith or microservices apps, just the same. And microservices can be multi-module maven apps. These are different level concepts. Maven is a project description tool. Microservice is a multi app architecting pardigm. Nothing opposes them. Or maybe I misunderstood your question and you could clarify ?

Comment: like @GPI said, they are tools to organise code and other processes, and  `LDD (Layer driven development)`  example can be `ejb project structures` , `DDD (Domain Driven Development)` example in **erp** you have inventory (microservice1) and user (microservice2) but both may have complex use case so *either or both of them can or cannot be LDD* rest is preference (like how fine grained services you want, others...)

Comment: @GPI maven is not a `Maven is a project description tool`  Maven is a build tool...

Comment: @khmarbaise even better. First line of maven.apache.org, `Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool.` Does not really change the crux of the issue, though.

Answer (score 5):

Some advice from Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html
Basically it says build a monolith first, and only once you have some working features, decide if and how you can split it up in multiple microservices.

The biggest advantage IMHO for microservices is independent deployability: you can develop, qa and deploy one microservice without worrying about the others. But that advantage only shines when you work with multiple teams.

Some issues you mentioned about microservices:

- Typically you have two access patterns between microservices: sending commands and listening for events. You can't do both with a REST API, sooner or later you'll need some Messaging infrastructure as well. Or use GraphQL.
- Access between microservices needs to be secured. For both REST API's and Messaging you would typically create an API Key for each microservice that is allowed to use it.
- Never share utilities or files between microservices, or you'll break the independent deployability. If shared resources are really needed, create a dedicated microservice that exposes the shared resource or utility function via a REST API.

But first: create a monolith and discover if and where you need microservice boundaries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uwe Friedrichsen just finished a 3-part blog series about the fallacy of reusable software modules: https://www.ufried.com/tags/reusability/